# Разделение чисел

Tags: python, list, split

Разделить числа от списка A до B и C, чтобы сумма (B) - сумма (C) была минимальной среди всех других вариантов.
А=[2,3,4,5], B = [2,5], C = [3,4]

```
def group(iterable, count):
    """ Группировка элементов последовательности по count элементов """
 
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * count)
```

Этот код используется для полного разделения.Но как быть в том случае,когда надо наоборот

Comment: Что наоборот???

Comment: Что бы разделялось не как [2,3] [4,5] а как [2,5] [3,4]

Comment: Да можно конечно, но чем это вам поможет? `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,100]` как по вашему нужно разбивать?

Comment: list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,100]
from itertools import zip_longest
def chunks(lst, count):
    n = len(lst) // count

    return list(x for x in zip_longest(*[iter(lst)] * n))

Comment: И что получится? по условию задачи должно получиться `B=[100]`, `C=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` Гуглите задачу о рюкзаке. вместимость рюкзака - половина суммы `sum(A)`

Comment: Почему В=[100] ?

Comment: Ну потому, что `100 - (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)` = `64`, это минимум. также как для `[2,3,4,5]` минимумом будет `(2+5)-(3+4) = 0`

Comment: в условие нужно добавить, что сумма по модулю, или поровну, или как-то ещё. Иначе, `B,C=[],A`

Answer (score 0):

Можно отсортировать массив от большего к меньшему, потом по очереди распределять по двум массивам (Условие будет работать только для положительных чисел. Для отрицательных придется дописать):

```
def divByMinSumDiff(arr):
  arr.sort(reverse=True)
  A, sumA = [], 0
  B, sumB = [], 0

  for num in arr:
    if sumA >= sumB:
      B.append(num)
      sumB += num
    else:
      A.append(num)
      sumA += num

  print( A, B, sumB - sumA )

divByMinSumDiff( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,100] )   # [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] [100] 64
divByMinSumDiff( [0,6] )                   # [0] [6] 6
divByMinSumDiff( [2,3,4,5] )               # [4, 3] [5, 2] 0
divByMinSumDiff( [1,0,5,0,5,0,1] )         # [5, 1, 0, 0, 0] [5, 1] 0
```

Comment: При `[3,3,2,2,2]` должно получиться `[3,3]` и `[2,2,2]` а не `[3,2]` и `[3,2,2]`. Жадный алгоритм не сможет дать оптимальный результат во всех случаях.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,3,4,5]

mini = 1

for i in a:

    for j in a:
        if i != j:


            k = 0
            while a[k] == i or a[k] == j:
                k+=1

            l = 0
            while a[l] == i or a[l] == a[k] or a[l] == j:
                l+=1
            if mini > ((i+j) - (a[k]+a[l])):
                mini = ((i+j) - (a[k]+a[l]))
                ans = str((i,j))+'-'+str((a[l],a[k]))
print(mini,ans)
```

Ответом будет: -4  (2, 3) - (5, 4)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Cтарый добрый перебор не подходит?
Долго? зато правильно ))

```
import itertools as it

def clastering(nubms):
    if len(numbs) == 2:
        return ([numbs[0]], [numbs[1]], abs(numbs[0] - numbs[1]))

    indexes = list(range(len(numbs)))
    sum_numbs  = sum(numbs) 
    min_diff = sum_numbs 
    res_index_set = indexes

    for elements in range(1, len(numbs)//2+1):
        for set_ in it.combinations(indexes, elements):
            rez = abs(sum_numbs - 2*sum([numbs[i] for i in set_]))
            if  rez < min_diff:
                min_diff, res_index_set = rez, set_
                if rez == 0:
                    break

    part1 = []
    for i in res_index_set:
       part1.append(numbs[i])

    part2 = numbs.copy()
    for numb in part1:
        part2.remove(numb)

    return (part1,part2,min_diff)
```